# Can you stop a defered callback in jquery 1.5?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.5, jquery-deferred

I am wondering say you have something like this

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: "example.php" })
    .success(function(response) { alert("success"); })


// perform other work here ...

// Set another success function for the request above
jqxhr.success(function(response){ alert("second success"); });
```

So I am thinking this. I have a general function that I want to use on all my responses that would be passed into my success.

This function basically does a check to see if the server validation found any errors. If it did they it formats it and displays a message.

Now I am wondering if I could some how have the second success function to then do specific stuff. Like say One ajax request needs to add a row into a table. So this should be possible. I just do what I have above and in the second success I just add the row.

Is it possible though that if the first success runs through and see that there are validation errors from the server that I can stop the second success from happening?

Sort of

```
If(first success finds errors)
{
   // print out errors
   // don't continue onto next success
}
else
{
   // go to next success 
}
```

**Edit**

I found that there is something call [deferred.reject](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.reject/)  and this does stop it but I am wondering how can I specify to stop only the success one. Since my thinking is if there are other deffered ones like complete on it will the be rejected too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one validation check function you could create your own deferred and attach handlers to that, rather than directly to the ajax request.

This example gives a single level of validation, if you want to chain them together you may need a different pattern.

```
var validated = function(jqxhr, validationFunction){
    var myDeferred = new $.Deferred();
    var doValidation = function(){
        var result = validationFunction.apply(this, arguments);
        if (result){
            myDeferred.resolve(arguments);
        }
        else
        {
            myDeferred.reject(arguments);
        }
    };

    jqxhr.success(doValidation);
    return myDeferred;
};

var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: "/echo/json/"});
var vtest = validated(jqxhr, function(response){
    //Do your validation check here,
    //return true if it passed, false if it failed.
    return false; 
});

//attach your handlers to vtest
vtest.done(function(response){alert("yay");});
vtest.fail(function(response){alert("drats");});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your second success function when your first success function evaluates the response from the AJAX call, and determines that it meet your requirements

example:

```
$.post('example.php', {name_1: value_1, name_2: value_2}, function(response){
  //this code gets executed when the AJAX request was successful

  //do some more stuff

  //check the response
  if(response == 'success'){
    second_success_function(response);
  }
});
```

This example assumes you get the string 'success' when everything went as planned.

The second argument in the $.post call is a map of values you pass to the script. This is optional.

You can also asign a handler to be executed when all AJAX requests have completed.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no, you can't use a [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)  (*as of jQuery v1.5 `.ajax()` objects extend deferred objects*) like that.

When you are adding callbacks to your [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) i.e. `.success(.....` they are stacked up. As soon as your deferred object [resolves](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) (*when the ajax finishes successfully*) it will run all callbacks that were stacked. Its too late to then try and [reject](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.reject/) the object for example to stop any more success callbacks being run. *Take a look at the example [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/fmCax/)*

It maybe better to perform the logic you need in your success function and call a wrapper function which will take care of any repetitive actions and call it from success if your logic tests pass.

---

Update as per the comments:

```
var cs = true;
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ 
    beforeSend: function(){
        cs=true;
    },
    url: "/echo/json/" 
})

.success(function(response) { 
    if(cs)
    alert("success"); 
})

.success(function(response) { 
    if(cs)
        cs = false;
        alert("success 2"); 
})

.success(function(response) { 
    if(cs)
        alert("success 3"); 
});
```

Using logic to kill off the callbacks.

Comment: When I tried rejecting it did stop my second success from running. If I understand you right the reason why it probably worked is that in the first success is where the reject is done so it technically has not finished?

Comment: @Scoobler- I don't get then what the point to have multiple success callbacks. I thought maybe it is so you could do something like I am trying to do but this does not seem like the case.

Comment: Not really, my understanding of it is, when you create the object, it will stack up all the callbacks _(successes)_ then once the object is finished _(either reject or resolve has been called)_ it will then process the stack. After all they are callbacks, something to be performed once the object has finished doing its thing - they don't flow, i.e. line by line. Take another look at this _[__update__](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/fmCax/1/)_. The other thing is, once the object receives the call to resolve, it isn't then meant to be changed or rejected I don't think.

Comment: Realistically there is no point in stacking success callbacks. Its just that you can do. Really what jQuery has acheived by making `.ajax()` a deferred object is to allow you to interact with the object more openly. So you could use `.then()` instead of `.success()` and `.done()' instead of `.complete()`. You __COULD__ possibly use some logic throughout the callbacks though.

Comment: See the update the question. Its not the prettiest, basically before the ajax call, set a flag `cs` _(coninue success)_ to true. As long as its true, continue. Trouble is, if you had a few ajax calls run at the same time, the global `var cs` could be affected by the wrong callback.